# Jquery Ajax + adblockplus

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

im trying to make a call to a service with jquery ajax that it is blocked by adblockplus (abp) since the service has "ads" as subdomain, the issue is that when abp blocks this call, kills all my code instead of going to error handler or going to the try catch exception.

There is any way to prevent abp kill my code? My code looks like:

```
try{
  $.ajax({
    url:"ads.service.com",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    success: function(){
      //something here
    },
    error: function(){
      //something else here
    }
  })
}catch(err){
  //something else here
}
```

Comment: Not really - that's how adblock works.

Comment: Sure, use a different subdomain, or a proxy that abp doesn't block.

Comment: Thanks for you answers, I find that adding a timeout makes the error method launches after the specified time.